# How can I install Windows Vista from one computer onto a HDD that will be used on a different computer?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installation

How can I install Windows Vista from Computer A onto a HDD that is connected to Computer A through a SATA-to-USB connector?

My intention is *not* have this HDD to function as an alternative OS to boot into, but rather to  later install this HDD onto Computer B and have it run on Computer B so that it can get into Windows. I just want to use Computer A to install Windows Vista onto the HDD which Computer B will later use.

Is this possible?

Comment: I know of no way to do what you asked, however: You can put the HDD as only disk in computer A, install vista, run sysprep generalise, and then move the HDD to computer B.

Comment: Yeah, sysprep will be required as the hardware will likely be different in B. Why can't you install in B directly BTW?

Comment: @Karan For some reason which I'm not sure of, I keep getting a 0xc00000e9 "I/O Error" when booting from the Vista installation disc on Computer B. I don't think my HDD has problem because my Computer A can read and write files onto the HDD when connected through a SATA-to-USB cable. So, I thought perhaps I could try installing Windows from Computer A.

Comment: I/O Error? I would still advise you to download the HDD manufacturer's utility and test the drive thoroughly for defects. You can also try installing Vista from a USB stick instead - maybe that will work if there's some problem with your DVD drive/cabling.